# Scaling a custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom layout derived from RelativeLayout. I want the custom layout to scale depending on the size of the container layout it's put it.

This is what I have so far for my custom layout:

```
public class ScaledRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private static final float HEIGHT = 460;
    private static final float WIDTH = 380;
    private float scale = 1.0f;
    private float pivotX = 0.0f;
    private float pivotY = 0.0f;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    public ScaledRelativeLayout( Context cxt, AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super( cxt, attrs );
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw( Canvas canvas ) {
        canvas.save();

        View parent = (View)getParent();
        int parentHeight = parent.getHeight();
        int parentWidth = parent.getWidth();

        float scaleX = (float)parentWidth / WIDTH;
        float scaleY = (float)parentHeight / HEIGHT;
        scale = Math.min( scaleX, scaleY );

        pivotX = (float)parentWidth / 2;
        pivotY = 0;

        canvas.scale( scale, scale, pivotX, pivotY );

        super.dispatchDraw( canvas );

        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

This almost works. Problem is the custom view is getting cropped at the bottom for some reason. It's as if the clipping region is too small when the view is drawn.

Comment: The fact you're specifying fixed values for your final `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` fields and then adjusting your `Canvas` accordingly means effectively you are working on an 'absolute' layout principle. Are you really sure you want to do that? Is there a particular reason why you don't want to allow the OS to auto-adjust according to screen size and density?

Comment: When I let the OS decide it scales the custom layout by the width which is fine as long as the container has a greater height than the custom layout. If the container is shorter than the custom layout it crops off the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are doing a uniform scale of `scale = Math.min( scaleX, scaleY );` this may cause problems in width and height since it depends on the minimum of two.

try a nonuniform scaling to scale the canvas to fit the screen

```
canvas.scale( scaleX, scaleY, pivotX, pivotY );
```

Comment: But I need the custom layout to scale uniformly so that it's contents aren't stretched out in one direction or the other. There's no guarantee as to the dimensions of the container.